# For experts: What's the replacement for fast conditional (cond ? true : false) in objects using PHP?

Tags: php, object, conditional-statements, call

For many of you maybe this is a stupid question, but today I've come across with a doubt:

There is a way to use fast cond ? true : false on object calls without the necessity to recreate code or use if/else statement? Let me explain...

How to call something like this?:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('votes', '>', 100)
                    (condition ? '->orWhere('name', 'John')' : '')
                    ->get();
```

Did you get it? Inside the object call...

Comment: I seriously doubt that you can do that for chained calls. You need to use if/else on the `$users` instance before the `->get()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). And no, you can't do what you want. You will have to use a regular if statement.

```
$query = DB::table('users')
                ->where('votes', '>', 100);
if (condition) {
    $query->orWhere('name', 'John');
}
$users = $query->get();
```